# How to find DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH and DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME in xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, dwarf

I am using the Crashlytics in order to report the crash occurs in the iOS app. Here, I want to know how to find the path of these below dwarf folder and file in xcode:

***DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH***

***DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to go to Organizer and select your archive file, select show in finder

[image]

after that you need to select show package content

[image]

and finally there is your `DYSM` folder

[image]

Comment: Organizer is under "Window" in Xcode (for anyone like me who didn't know)

Answer (score 56):

You can do it using `xcodebuild` tool:

```
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target MyTarget -showBuildSettings
```

Output of this command will contain Xcode env values including `DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH` and `DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME`.

Comment: Best solution to get complete path for all sources.

Comment: best answer useful I have seen  ---- have a nice day

Comment: Complete solution indeed!

Answer (score 5):

If you have a workspace and multiple schemes, you can use the following command from the `xcodebuild` tool.

```
xcodebuild -workspace Project.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectSceheme -showBuildSettings
```